# Estimated battery stuck in 100% while discharging

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery, indicator, ubuntu-gnome

So, my estimated battery charge remains since yesterday at 100% while the remaining time reads 135 hours and 19 minutes.

I wish it was true, but I'm pretty sure it wont last that long.

I've been having this issue since yesterday. My laptop (ACER Aspire R) was at 77% charge, I left my workstation for literally two minutes to get a book from the shelf and when I returned it was suspended (note: I have that option disabled). I turn it on, log in, and battery indicator is showing 0%, so I plug in the power source and in 5 minutes it goes up to 100% and its been up there since yesterday although it's not plugged to the electricity anymore.

Already tried calibrating from terminal, but "device does not have any RAPL domains cannot power measure power usage".

The battery is new. I've had it for two months and it's been working as intended until yesterday.

Comment: Is the battery genuine or 3rd party compatible?

Comment: My battery had similar issues, and it stopped working completely within two months. Consider replacing the battery.

Comment: it's 3rd party compatible. As I said, it's working as intended until yesterday, and even now it's working (I've been working for 2 hours straight already... my guess is I already have about 2 hours battery left). My issue is the charge percentage and time indicator It's showing 100% battery left

Comment: This is most certainly a sign that the battery is no longer trustworthy.